# STM32 and GDB - Watchpoint

Tags: stm32, gdb

I'm reading the book http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~geobrown/book.pdf and I have a question regarding the Exercise 3.1.2 on page 50.

It ask to set a watchpoint on i. I set a watchpoint but it never break the code. I tried breakpoint a function as the book said and it worked.

It is related to tool stlink?

thanks :)

Comment: It may be that this does not work; watchpoints are tricky to support, extremely so if the variable is not declared volatile.  There are almost always alternative techniques you can employ with a little creative thinking.

Answer (score 2):

If the source code was compiled so that it could be easily debugged (typically the switch -g) then you can just call in your GDB client:

```
watch x
```

Where x is the variable in your code you want to watch. Although its highly likely that it might not be supported by your GDB client for you microcontroller.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the optimization flag -O1 and now the watch works :)